# Relacionamento One-To-One com EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando criar um relacionamento `OneToOne` com EF6. No meu esquema tenho uma classe de Usuario e uma de Plano e o relacionamento seria 1 Usuario tem 1 Plano, porem, esse relacionamento é feito quando o Usuario paga o Plano que então faço o relacionamento.

Usei o `HasOptional<Plano>(u => u.plano)` para fazer o mapeamento do lado do Usuario, salvo as informações no banco de dados normalmente com o relacionamento, o problema é que quando faço uma busca o Plano não retorna junto com o Usuario e não sei pq isso acontece.

Como resolver isso ?

```cs
public class Usuario
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public Plano plano { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Plano
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento:

```cs
public class UsuarioMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Usuarios");
        this.HasKey<long>(u => u.id);
    
        this.HasOptional<Plano>(u => u.plano);
    }
}
```

No código abaixo, a propriedade `Plano` fica nula.

```cs
Usuario usuario = context.usuarios.Where(u => u.id == usuarioSession.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar o método `Include(x => x.NomeDaSuaEntidade)` junto a chamada do context quando for retornar entidades relacionadas a sua model.

Porém além disso você deve também colocar uma propriedade de *Foreign Key* (chave estrangeira) que permite que o banco identifique qual campo relaciona as duas entidades, ou seja suas models deveriam ficar assim:

```
public class Usuario{
    public long id                  { get; set; }
    public virtual Plano plano      { get; set; }

public class Plano{
    [ForeignKey("Usuario")]
    public long id                   { get; set; }
```

Após configurar suas entidades corretamente, pode fazer a chamada a seguir para pegar os Usuários e os Planos relacionados a eles.

```
Usuario usuario = context.usuarios.Include(x => x.plano).Where(u => u.id == usuarioSession.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ao invés de `Include(x => x.plano)` eu usei o `Include("Plano")` e funcionou blzinha. Obrigado.